# Autonumbering based on other column

Tags: vba, excel

I get a file I want to process via a macro in excel.

1. Column A holds values from 1-10
2. Column C holds a value in C1
3. For each value 6 in column A, the corresponding cell in Column C in the same row should be updated with a sequentially incremented value starting from the value in C1.

I had something like below, but that gave many issues, but it shows the concept I am looking for.

```
Sub customernumberext()
    Dim a As Range, i As Long

    Range("C1").Select
    If ActiveCell.Value <> Empty Then
        i = "C1"
        For Each a In ActiveSheet.Range("a:a") where a.value = "6"
           row c = i
           i = i + 1
         Next a
     Else: MsgBox ("no number present")
     End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Michiel, here we don't do code optimization but we help fixing a specific problem. If your code works fine and you want to optimize, I'd suggest you to post the question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Otherwise, please ask one question per time: run your code, see the error message, google it, try to fix it and if you don't succeed come back and post the precise question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your description and errant code correctly, this should solve the problem.

```
Sub incr_C()
    Dim rw As Long, lr As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For rw = 2 To lr
            If .Cells(rw, 1).Value = 6 Then
                .Cells(rw, 3) = Application.Max(Range("C1:C" & rw - 1)) + 1
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I am still trying to understand it, but it works perfect :-) thank you so much for the solution! I have been sweating on it for days, great to be able to enjoy the sunday :-)